# Parent linear layout not taking up entire screen despite having fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a strange issue right now with a parent linear layout, I have its height set to fill_parent yet it seems intent on wrapping the content instead, what really is puzzling me even more is that in the graphical layout view its showing up the way Im intending for it to look but yet its still not doing what It should in the emulator?

here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/title_color_dark_transparent" >

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/menutweetedittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
            android:lines="4"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menucharactersremaining"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/characters"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menuposttweetbutton"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:onClick="posttweetbuttonClicked"
                android:text="@string/postbuttonstext"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/menuadView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14f5be094d0328"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have several LinearLayout children. Which one has the problem?

Comment: which of those LinearLayouts it the one thats not fullscreen?

Comment: the parent, I have set a background color for the first one which is to take up the entire screen and its just wrapping the content on the screen Instead

Comment: sorry I think I meant to say the base layout? but the first one anyway

Comment: This is by far the most frustrating problem Ive ever seen since working with android, especially because everything is done correctly

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot at simplifying your layout.  I ditched all your styling, but maybe the objects are in the right places.  Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/menutweetedittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
    android:lines="4"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menuposttweetbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menutweetedittext"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="posttweetbuttonClicked"
    android:text="Tweet"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menucharactersremaining"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/menuposttweetbutton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/menuposttweetbutton"
    android:text="This is the text view"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menuadView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I solved it, I was in the process of changing the theme from a dialog theme to a translucent them and forgot to remove getwindow from the java code, I figured this out after I decided to go from theme.translucent.notitlebar to theme.translucent, the title bar sitting centrally helped me finally clue into what I was doing wrong lol

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it sorted out.